# Automatic variable assignment?

Tags: java

Newbie question:

I have two classes:

```
class A {
    public static void main(String...args){
        B b = new B()
        System.out.println(B.firstVar); // 0
    }
}

class B {
    public int firstVar;
}
```

Why does it print 0 when no value was assigned to firstVar ?

Comment: default value of the integer is 0

Comment: note that integer-type instance variables are automatically initialized by 0 in both C++ and Java, whereas integer-type local variables are automatically initialized in Java only

Comment: @mangusta no local variables are initialized automatically in java see link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: @TheMohanAhuja yes, you're right :) I confused with "C++ gives no compile-time error for uninitialized local variables while Java gives compilation error"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing There are two error in your code

One is missing semicolon:

```
 B b = new B()
```

Second is trying to use non-static member with class name

```
System.out.println(B.firstVar);
```

It should be

```
System.out.println(b.firstVar);
```

**Answer to your question:** When a constructor is called it initializes member variable/ properties of class to respective type default values.

```
Type    Default Value (for fields)
byte    0
short   0
int     0
long    0L
float   0.0f
double  0.0d
char    '\u0000'
String (or any object)      null
boolean     false
```

That's why even without initialization it prints `0`

**Note:** Local variables are slightly different; the compiler never assigns a default value to an uninitialized local variable.

Answer (score 2):

0 value is the default value for the int type.

here are some other default values:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 0):

Thats the way Java initilializes variables.
For example int is initialized with `0` and Objects with `null`

```
Object obj; // obj is null
int i; // i is 0
double d; //d is 0
```

Answer (score 0):

When you don't set anything to the variable, it is assigned a zero  by default (in case of int)